# Netbeans with Qt5: No rule to make target

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, makefile, qmake

I'm compile Qt5 project from NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

I keep getting this error message:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-Release_Win32.mk QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/usr/bin/qmake VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Release_Win32.mk nbproject/qt-Release_Win32.pro
mv -f qttmp-Release_Win32.mk nbproject/qt-Release_Win32.mk
"make" -f nbproject/qt-Release_Win32.mk dist/Release_Win32/MinGW-w32-Linux-x86/Application
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sabo/workspace/project1'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'dist/Release_Win32/MinGW-w32-Linux-x86/Application'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sabo/workspace/project1'
nbproject/Makefile-Release_Win32.mk:65: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
```

In file Makefile-Release_Win32.mk I have this build target:

```
.build-conf: ${BUILD_SUBPROJECTS} nbproject/qt-${CND_CONF}.mk
"${MAKE}" -f nbproject/qt-${CND_CONF}.mk ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/Application
```

But in file qt-Release_Win32.mk I have other target:

```
...
DESTDIR_TARGET = dist/Release_Win32/MinGW-w32-Linux-x86/Application.exe
...
$(DESTDIR_TARGET):  $(OBJECTS) build/Release_Win32/MinGW-w32-Linux-x86/Application_resource_res.o
$(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) -o $(DESTDIR_TARGET) $(OBJECTS)  $(LIBS)
```

How to cahnge DESTDIR_TARGET in auto-generated qt-Release_Win32.mk file?

Comment: I would personally avoid other IDEs as long as Qt Creator is good one on Linux as well. The only good IDE besides Creator is Visual Studio but it builds slower (no jom with qt VS AddIn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hotfix:

In project settings:
Set target as Application.exe

And add Qt variable 
TARGET=Application

It's work.

Answer (score 1):

What acts as .pro file in your build? That file is consumed by qmake so you should first make a change there and then run qmake and then build using jom or make or whatever uses qmake output.

[QMAKE docs: how to customize MyApp.pro file](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir-target):

DESTDIR

Specifies where to put the target file.

For example:

DESTDIR = ../../lib

DESTDIR_TARGET

This variable is set internally by qmake, which is basically the DESTDIR variable with the TARGET variable appened at the end. The value of this variable is typically handled by qmake or qmake.conf and rarely needs to be modified.